# Override application--wrap class in Vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify js in an application and am facing a lot of responsive screen issues for smaller devices. Upon inspecting I realised it was because of the "application--wrap" class provided by Vuetify. I was hoping to remove the "--wrap" part from the class or maybe increase the max-width property of it. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is ideal, but you can override this with CSS by using `.override`. Reference: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/conditionally-overriding-application-wrap/34076

Comment: Hello, thank you for reaching out, I tried using .override method, it did not work out as expected, it barely made any difference even with using ! mportant in styling